# How to migrate from log4j2 to logback?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

I'm planning to move from log4j2 to logback in my spring boot project. But I'm facing logback configuration issues when I try to start the application.

## Error:

```
    {Application startup failed}"}java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@44:19 - no applicable action for [messageFormat], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][messageFormat]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@45:16 - no applicable action for [includeMDC], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][includeMDC]]
```

So, I have done the following steps:

1. Removed all log4j2 dependencies and added logback-classic maven dependency.
2. And replaced log4j2.xml file with logback.xml file.

And I have splunk appender in my configuration

## And my logback configuration:

```
    <Property name="SPLUNK_PATTERN" value='{"source":"${hostName}","host”:”XXXX”,
            "event":{"date":"%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}","service":"${serviceName}","traceId":"%X{X-B3-TraceId}","spanId":"%X{X-B3-SpanId}","thread":"%t","level":"%level","class":"%c", "message":"%msg"}}' />


<appender name="http" class="com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender">
            <url>https://xxx/xxx/collector</url>
            <token>xxx</token>
            <host>xxx</host>
            <source>${hostName}</source>    
            <messageFormat>json</messageFormat>
            <includeMDC>false</includeMDC>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>${SPLUNK_PATTERN}</pattern>
            </layout>
</appender>
```

## pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.splunk.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>splunk-library-javalogging</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Can anyone please help me out regarding the same ....

Comment: What is the appender defaulted in logback.xml, Please post the logback.xml, Also, for maven dependencies, are they checked with `dependency:tree` ?

Comment: mvn dependency:tree  -Dtokens=extended

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've fired the mvn dependency:tree -Dtokens=extended and excluded some of the duplicate dependencies. But, my concern is , how can I convert log4j2 pattern to logback pattern ? Currently, I'm using the log4j2 splunk pattern due to which I'm facing pattern issues . Can you please help me out ....